# Bash command not found on VS Code on Window

Tags: ruby, bash, visual-studio-code

I´m having trouble executing the code on VS Code, I keep getting the command is not found (below), could someone please tell me what I should do or what I'm doing wrong, Thank you.

~/OneDrive/Desktop/advanced_methods_exercise
$ ruby 01_coprime.rb
bash: ruby: command not found

Comment: Please be more descriptive in describing your problems. It helps us to understand your situation better and could help the readers to tackle them.

Answer (score 0):

The details on this problem is very little. However, if you are trying to get Ruby installed in your (windows) system, you can refer to their official site: [ruby official site](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/)

However, there is a easier way to install ruby (in windows) by using the package manager - [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install).

Once you have chocolatey installed, simply install Ruby by the following command: `choco install ruby`, reference:  [install ruby using choco](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/ruby)